# Using ng2-translate with parameters

Tags: angular, ng2-translate

I tried to use ng2-translate with parameters in the template:

```
{{ test | translation:{value:param} }}
```

And it works perfectly. I would like to build my translation in my typescript and I saw this function:

```
get(key: string|Array<string>, interpolateParams?: Object): Observable<string|Object>
```

But I don't know how to use it.

Do you guys have any example ?

My case is:

en.json:

```
{ "test":"the level of {value1} and {value2} is low."}
```

typescript:

```
let message:string = "";
let parametres = ["1", "2"];
this._translateService.get("test", parametres).subscribe((res:string) => {
    message += res;
});
```

I would like to have: The level of 1 and 2 is low.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you actually using a `translation` pipe? Shouldn't that be `translate`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works when you provide key/values as parameters instead of an array.

typescript:

```
let message:string = "";
let parametres = {value1: "1", value2: "2"};
this._translateService.get("test", parametres).subscribe((res:string) => {
    message += res;
});
```

Also according to the docs you should declare the placeholders with double curly braces.

en.json:

```
{ "test": "the level of {{value1}} and {{value2}} is low." }
```

Comment: You should also check if the Observable returned by get hangs. In my case, the translation was not fully loaded and the Observable never returned anything.

Comment: I tried to put it in a map and it does not work. I'm gonna try in an object directly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 21):

In en_US.json file, follow the below format to include x and y (which will be our parameters that we want to replace with numbers.

```
{"Showing": "Showing {{x}} of {{y}}"}
```

In component.ts, min,max will be the variables that we populate.

```
  min: number;
  max: number;
```

and following will be part of component.html

```
<span> {{ 'Showing' | translate:{x: min, y: max} }} </span>
```

Comment: @AJQarshi j Q gives the following error for me:  _Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected } at the end of the expression [{{'XXXXXXX' | translate:{ minValue: 50, maxValue: 100 }}}]_

Comment: @Hany You are missing a space. That's the issue. Use `[{{'student.certificateInfo.grade.range' | translate:{ minValue: 50, maxValue: 100 } }}]`. Please note the space at the end `} }}]`.

Comment: @AJQarshi j Q    Oooh!...Worked!...unexpected reason for the error, Thanks